# Org export on mac os # option

Tags: org-mode, org-export, osx

When I press `C-c C-e` in org mode I get the export options. However I can not choose "Insert template" as when I try and type the `#` in mac os I need to press the `option` key and the `3` key. But `Option` is the meta key. How can I get to the insert template option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```lisp
(setq mac-right-option-modifier 'none) ;; unbind right key for accented input
```

Though for my mac you use shift and 3 to get the '#' sign. But in any case it is good to keep one of the 'option' keys free for modifiers.

Comment: It's uk keyboard so shift 3 gets £